# No power in outlets after changing light switches

Tags: electrical, switch, receptacle, smart-switch

This is a room with a two switch board and some power outlets. One Switch was controlling the fan and other it's light. Outlets, switches and fan+light were all working fine until I wanted to change the switches to smart ones. All connections appear snug tight and when I turn on power, one of the switches get power (its little indicator light glows), the other switch gets no power (indicator not glowing), fan AND light won't turn on irrespective of the switch status, most curious part is, outlets are all dead. It didn't trip as the first switch is getting power. Outlets aren't controlled by switches. What could be going wrong?

Note:
The only thing I changed from existing wiring is the neutrals(white wires). neutrals weren't connected with the existing switches but 4 of them twisted together. I took 2 of them out and connected to each new switch (manual specifically asked me to do so). Otherwise, i was just recreating what was already there but with new switches.

This is how it looks:
[image: overview]
[image: closeup of the box]
[image: box and switches]

And this one is just a view from below to see that one of the switches receives power, whereas the other doesnt.
[image: switch receiving power]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the wiring inside the box please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to get all those neutrals together

Your problem is that you split the neutrals up instead of bundling them together; thus, power has no way to get *back* from the other switch, the lights, and the outlets to the utility.  The easy fix is to turn the power off at the breaker, unbundle the white neutral wires, bundle them *all* together with a big enough wirenut, button things up, and turn the breaker back on, then things should work.